# How can I pass tenant value in the URL via Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2

I have a multi tenant API and I am trying to RESTIFY it using wso2. I am trying a way to pass the tenant value in the url.

localhost:8290//tenant/api/...

https://tenant.xyz.com/api/...

I tried İntegration studio and i managed to pass a literal tenant value in http endpoint by creating a property named {uri.var.tenant} and setting it to tenant name. However, I don't know how can I take the tenant name from here

localhost:8290//tenant/api

and pass it here.

https://tenant.xyz.com/api/

I also tried using the APIM publisher page with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, there are 2 parts for your question.

1. How to parameterize the backend URL.
2. How to read the path parameter from the fronting API that is being called.

For the first one, the method you have followed is correct and an example can be found at https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/examples/endpoint_examples/using-http-endpoints/#example-1-populating-an-http-endpoint-during-mediation . What's remaining is to read the path parameter and to populating {uri.var.tenant} which is the second point.

For the second point, you can create and API definition with the URL templated. See the property URI Template at https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/synapse-properties/rest-api-properties/ you can find an example of the usage at https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/examples/rest_api_examples/setting-query-params-outgoing-messages/#reading-a-query-or-path-parameter